# How To keep your Window phone App run when press back button of hardware?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I a new in window phone app. I have some problem that I can't solve. I have built a sample app use web browser to play audio music online, I want to keep music play when I press back or start button (of hardware windows phone mobile), but actually, when I pressed it, the music have been stopped.

Comment: You're going to provide more information if you want people to help.  Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.  At a minimum, you need to post a minimal sample that reproduces the issue that you're having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Background agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to play music in the background. Your app must be close if the user press the back button, otherwise you will not allowed to publish it in the store.